# Monitor the PenDrive Actions

Tags: c#, usb

Net. i have developed a C# project to monitor the Pen-drive actions.
by using wndproc method i found the usb plugin and plug out actions through the device change event occurs. but i don't know how to find what are all the files copied from pen-drive to pc and vice-versa and also block the user to access the pen-drive for particular time after inserting the pendrive. please provide me the solution or any idea. thanks in advance. sorry for my bad English. I provided the sample code for device change event below

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            try
            {
                var drvs = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(drives => drives.IsReady && drives.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);

                //0x0219 device change.
                //0x8000 device arrival.
                //0x8004 device removal complete.
                //0x00000002 device type volume.
                /*if (m.Msg == 0x0219)
                {
                    ejectUSB();
                    /*if (m.Msg == 0x8004)
                    {
                        Thread thread = new Thread(ejectUSB);
                        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                        thread.Start();
                        writeLog("Enters for USB Ejection ");
                    }*
                }*/
                switch (m.Msg)
                {
                    case WM_DEVICECHANGE: OnDeviceChange(ref m); break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                writeLog(e.ToString());
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        void OnDeviceChange(ref Message msg)
        {
            int wParam = (int)msg.WParam;
            if (wParam == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
            {
                writeLog("Enters for USB Ejection ");
                ejectUSB();
                //MessageBox.Show("Device Arrived");
            }
            else if (wParam ==  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE)
            {
                writeLog("USB is Removed ");
                //MessageBox.Show("Device Removed");
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Enumerating drivers on every windows message is bad idea imho.

Comment: @Sinatr then can you please provide me any other idea

Comment: I don't know where you use it, but simply move it inside switch processing code (msg -> w.Param -> enumerate drivers).

Comment: @Sinatr you mean that move DriveInfo.GetDrivers() code is to be moved into the switch statement am i right.